# Remove a field from felogin extension's backend typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I need to remove certain fields like company, email etc from fe_users backend for my felogin extension. How it is possible with typo3 7.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What fields are available in the backend is determined what is written in the TCA. You might remove the fields from TCA, but that could cause problems if there is some code which assumes the fields exist.

So it's better to remove the fields only from the display list (`$GLOBALS['TCA']['fe_users']['interface']['showRecordFieldList']`).

1. use a file /Configuration/TCA/Overlay/fe_users.php to modify the global TCA.
2. use TSconfig to disable the fields. e.g. `TCEFORM.fe_users.company.disabled = 1`